# No wife, no pregnancy, but the son is already named

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

> **No  wife, not  her  pregnancy but  the  son's  name  is   soma  lingam (some ×)**
>
> Aalu  ledu, chulu  ledu kani  koduku  peru  matram  somalingam. (Telugu)

Some people  think  of the future  happening  without  any base  in the  present. This  idiom  is used  to  talk  about  such  people  in  a humorous context.

_It  is  not  equal to  building  [castles  in the  air](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/build+castles+in+the+air) because  it  is  not  an  impossible  task  for  him to  marry  and  beget  a  son. He is  imagining  things  too  early.

The  idiom  is  used  to  talk  about   a  person who  talks  about  something  well  in  advance  without  any  scope  for  such  a  talk. A  married  man
may  talk  about   his/ her  son' s  being  christened but  it  is  a foolish  to  talk  about  the  name  of  a  son  well  before  his  marriage  without  having  a  wife.

Is  there  such  a   phrase  or   an idiom  in  English?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a term for polishing something too early?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171851/is-there-a-term-for-polishing-something-too-early) (putting the cart before the horse / jumping the gun / getting ahead of yourself / premature optimisation ...).

Comment: @Englishmonger people could be downvoting because it is similar to Edwin's duplicate, and upvoting the answers because that is what they would suggest. Votes do not correlate between questions and answers.

Comment: You keep asking questions about proverbs from a different culture, but show no evidence of any effort to find the answers yourself. How about buying a book of proverbs?

Comment: @ David. It  is  an  excellent  Idea. I  could  not  get  it

Comment: Look up "proverbs" + "list". Some might even be thematic (in which you'd find it easier to discover a proverb containing 'early', 'bird' and 'worm' if you didn't know it but knew you wanted one on the theme of 'punctuality').

Comment: @  so  you  want to  suggest  that  I  should  stop  asking  questions  on  idioms.Of course, I won't. But  some  users  are  very  eager  to  answer  them.The  difficult  thing  is  to  find  if  there  is  any duplicate  for  it. Then  why  are so  many  questions  asked on  proverbs  and  the  tag  is  existing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call this [getting ahead of yourself](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/get-ahead-of-yourself).

> You have named your son soma lingam, but you are not married or pregnant. Aren't you getting ahead of yourself?

Answer (score 6):

This is [**putting the cart before the horse**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/put-the-cart-before-the-horse):

> to do things in the wrong order:
>
> - *Aren't you putting the cart before the horse by deciding what to wear for the wedding before you've even been invited to it?*